# Django как подставить в форме в поле файла значение из базы

Tags: python, django, forms

Мне надо на странице вывести из базы данные и картинку в форму.
Потом на этой же странице внести изменения в данные и отправить всё назад в базу.
Вот как выглядит view:

```
def demo_confirmation(request, serial):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DemoRegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect('demo_confirmation_list')
    else:
      purchase = DemoPurchase.objects.filter(serial=serial).first()
      form = DemoRegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      context = {
        'form': form,
        'purchase': purchase,
      }
      return render(request, 'demo_confirmation.html', context)
  else:
    purchase = DemoPurchase.objects.filter(serial=serial).first()
    form = DemoRegisterForm(instance=purchase)
    context = {
      'form': form,
      'purchase': purchase,
    }
    return render(request, 'demo_confirmation.html', context)
```

При создании страницы я получаю в поле ввода файла такую аннотацию:

[image: Скриншот]

И поле ввода оказывается пусто. Соответственно, когда я вношу изменения в данные, отправить их не получается т.к. надо заполнить поле `ImageInput`.

Подскажите, как подставить значение из базы а поле `ImageInput`.
По сути мне нужно обновить одно поле в записи базы.
Я пробовал `.save(update_fields=['confirmation'])`, но получаю ошибку

```
BaseModelForm.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields'
```

Answer (score 0):

Методом проб и ошибок нашёл решение.
Сначала берём значение формы и переводим в True\False

```
confirmation = request.POST.get('confirmation')
    if confirmation == 'on':
      confirmation = True
    else:
      confirmation = False
```

Далее кладём его объект и сохраняем

```
purchase.confirmation = confirmation
purchase.save(update_fields=['confirmation'])
```

Вот вроде ничего сложного, но прямого ответа в интернете не нашёл. Как буд-то я первый на этом споткнулся...